# Choosing Vds value for low-side switch

Tags: mosfet, switching

I want to switch a 24V DC water pump by a 5V DC from an Arduino. I think the best way to do it is by a logic level mosfet low side switching. To do so, the \$V_{DS}\$ value should be 24V or a much lower since most of the voltage drops on the load (water pump)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vds needs to be at least the supply voltage, as the full voltage will appear across the FET when it is off. Additionally, a DC motor will generate a sizable back EMF when switched off, so a freewheeling diode is necessary. Using a Schottky diode will prevent issues with recovery, other diodes will still have a short, but usually tolerable spike generated, and the FET needs to be capable of withstanding that.

[image: freewheel]

Comment: Thanks Phil. Can you expend on why the full voltage will appear across the FET when it's off? Why no voltage drops on the pump but it will on the FET?

Comment: With no current through the motor it has no potential across it. For DC motors, the majority of the potential across them while running is the back emf generated from motion, the resistance and hence resistive drop is low. That brings up another consideration - the starting current of such a motor is usually many times that of the running current, especially if it is starting up with a load like an impeller full of water. With an Arduino you can gradually run up the  PWM of an output to soft start it, or just ensure that the FET will tolerate the short term curent.

Comment: Is the fact that the full potential of the power supply is loaded on the FET true for all DC loads such as a motor, led, heating element, etc.?

Comment: Yes. With some non-linear loads, like LEDs, the current conducted by them below the forward conduction knee is very small, so the potential at the switching node will be a balance between the characteristics of that load and the leakage current through the FET, but as a standard practice you'd still choose a FET with a rating to allow for the highest supply voltage limit, usually plus some margin for reliability.

Answer (score 0):

You probably refer to Vgs Max, which is the maximum voltage the gate can be driven before the mosfet dies.

The actually switching voltage is the Gate threshold voltage and is much lower.

You can search for mosfet with low gate threshold voltage, usually the datasheet will provide a graph with the Vgs and the drain current.

The 24V will drop along the line if you drive the pump and there is significant current. However, the 5V from the Arduino driving the gate will not drop because the gate current is negligible.

Comment: I might have confused Vgs with Vds. I understand that the Vgs should be low (about 5v) for saturating the mosfet.I updated the question for Vds.

Comment: @OmriFarshi \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ should be around 1 V to 3 V so when you give it 5 V then it will be *very* turned on. Compared to *just barely activated* and barely functional and might burn up. [AO3402](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3402.pdf) is as usual a very good NMOS.